# How does remove seconds from being listed in the input bar of the Angular Moment Picker display?

Tags: momentjs

I'm using Angular moment picker which can be found at:
https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker
and

I'd like to only display the date-time up to the minute in the date-picker and not up to the second. There are configuration settings which can be changed via the moment-picker-provider. However, none of these seems to directly affect how the date-time is displayed in the input field once the former is selected. The only solutions I can currently think of involve either editing the directive source code itself or to implement a javascript workaround. Is there a way to do this with Angular Moment Picker or Moment.js?

Below, the image has the date-time set to "3/10/2016 10:30:53 AM". It should just read "3/10/2016 10:30 AM".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz1Ve.png)

Comment: No need to edit the directive source code, you can simply use [`format`](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker#options) option of the component. Anyway show the code you are using for the picker.

Answer (score 0):

found this:
https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker/issues/212

In short just add max-view="hour"

That removes the seconds, and then as VincenzoC suggested you can format it. Hope you manage.